# Spatial sequence of autumn leave colouring: top to bottom

Tags: plant-physiology, trees

Leave colours on trees seem to vary on the same tree from top to bottom. Leaves higher up are already further ahead in the shedding process. What's the reason for this tempero-spatial gradient?

[image: Different colours on same tree]